# How to build a split donut chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I need to build a pie/donut chart where the outer ring does not continue for the full circumference of the chart:

[image]

I've obviously managed to draw the chart but now need to treat the green slice as a single unit, even though it is really an inner and outer slice - have tried working with mouseOver/Out with no luck (changes on mouseOver, regex error on out):

In plotOptions { series { point { events I'm doing this:

```
mouseOver: function () {                                            
    if (this.name == "") {
        this.options.oldColor = this.color;
        this.update({
            color: 'red'                                                                     
        });                                                
    }
},
mouseOut: function () {                                         
    if (this.options.oldColor != null && this.name == "") {
        this.update({
            color: this.options.oldColor
        });
}
}
```

I need to keep tooltips on as well...

Any ideas?

Comment: Your question in the title and in the content doesn't match. What are you trying to do?

Comment: You can use `update()` in mouseOver/mouseOut handler, because it may remove graphic and produce error. Better solution is to use `this.graphic.attr(options)` where in options you can change color, by using `{fill: color}` or '{fillColor: color}`. If you will setup full example on jsFiddle with that issue we may help you more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved - added the event below to clear the default mouseOut function, then used .graphic.attr to make my changes.

```
events: {
    load: function () {
        var seriesPoints = this.series[0].points;
            for (var i = 0; i < seriesPoints.length; i++) {
                seriesPoints[i].onMouseOut = function () { };
                }
            }
        }
```